# hyphen in DLL name for VS reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, wix, windows-installer

First, some background. I'm working on an application that uses the [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) to create the installer. We frequently use WiX to control setting up our client's directories and place the needed DLLs where they need to go.

Now, on to the problem: I added a new DLL to my application, lets call it "NewCode.dll." NewCode.DLL has a dependency on "Dependency-1.DLL." So in order to make my program work, I need to also include Dependency-1.DLL in the installer. And this is where I get stuck. Because of the "-1" in the name of Dependency-1.DLL, Visual Studio doesn't seem to allow me to add it as a reference to the project. Without adding it as a reference, I don't believe WiX can find it, and so NewCode.DLL will fail at run time. Simply removing the hyphen is not an option because NewCode.DLL won't be able to reference Dependency-1.DLL anymore.

I have verified that if I manually place the Dependency-1.DLL into the required folder, everything will start working. So I suppose doing some "batch file post-build-action magic" to copy files around is a valid option, but its not ideal. I'd really prefer to continue to rely on the WiX Toolset.

---

Working answer:

The accepted solution did fix my problem. But I thought I'd add on to my post in case anyone else falls into the same trap I did. The first DLL is a direct reference, while the second is a transitive reference that the first depends on. I set the default location for the component group for where to look for the DLLs to be the TargetDir. With my old set up, this was assuming that VS would handle copying the DLL to the TargetDir for me via "Copy Local = true". Now, however, if you look at the second DLL that I'm adding, I set the source explicitly and WiX is moving the DLL for me.

Since WiX moves the DLL for me now, this gets me around the issue of VS not allowing the hyphenated DLL name as a reference.

```
<ComponentGroup Id="AForge" Directory="INSTALL_ROOT" Source="$(var.Pslf.TargetDir)">

<Component Guid="{FA5BEE4F-0D54-4B76-BAEF-DC8E31F6605F}">
        <File Name="AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>

<Component Guid="{1FB3EFEA-1BF3-4416-8AE3-026F2E4EECFC}">
        <File Name="avcodec-53.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)pslf\lib\AForge\avcodec-53.dll"/>
</Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Comment: What version of visual studio? I just added a reference to a known dll which worked, then removed that reference and renamed the dll to include "-1.dll" in the filename, and it let me add the new reference just fine. This is on visual studio 2015. "doesn't seem to allow me to add it as a reference to the project" -- so you *are* going to "Add->Reference"? And getting an error? What's the error?

Comment: I found a different solution, but the error message was that the "assembly file was invalid or not accessible." What struck me as odd, however, is that simply removing the hyphen from the name fixes this problem (just doesnt work for my purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a WiX reference to pre-built DLLs. Just put the direct path to it in the Source attribute:

```
<File Id="file_Dependency_1.DLL" Name="Dependency-1.DLL" KeyPath="yes"
        DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)path\to\dlls\Dependency-1.DLL" />
```